# didFinish delegate not getting called in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, wkwebview

I'm trying to hide a splash view when the `WKWebView` finishes loading. So in my `WebView.swift` file, I have a coordinater that contains the didFinish delegate. I've put a print statement inside of the didFinish delegate function, but when running the app, I do not see that print statement in my debug console once the webView finishes loading. I've tried using breakpoints aswell, and it makes no difference. Keep in mind that I have no errors showing aswell. Here's my `WebView.swift` file:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SwiftUiWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        let parent: SwiftUiWebView
        
        init(_ parent: SwiftUiWebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Done loading")
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> SwiftUiWebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    let url: URL?
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let prefs = WKWebpagePreferences()
        prefs.allowsContentJavaScript = true
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        config.defaultWebpagePreferences = prefs
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let myURL = url else {
            return
        }
       
        let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
        uiView.load(request)
    }
}
```

And `SwiftUiWebview` gets called in `ContentView.swift` like:

```
SwiftUiWebView(url: URL(string: "www.mywebsitename.com"))
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the navigation delegate on your `WKWebView` otherwise it will never be called.

You can do this in the `updateUIView` call by accessing your coordinator from the context and setting the `navigationDelegate` to be `context.coordinator`.

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    guard let myURL = url else {
        return
    }

    uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator // <- This sets the delegate

    let request = URLRequest(url: myURL)
    uiView.load(request)
}
```

Once you do that then all navigationDelegate functions should be called if you implement them.